# $C^*$ algebras and states

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, quantum-mechanics

I have a question arising from von Neumann's C*-algebra formulation of quantum mechanics. In it, a state is a $\mathbb{C}$-linear functional on a C*-algebra $A$

$\rho:A\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$

satisfying the following conditions:

- $\rho$ is *positive*: for every $a\in A$, we have $ \rho(a^*a) \geq 0 \in \mathbb{R}$;
- $\rho$ is *normalized*: $\rho(\mathbf{1}) = 1$.

By the Gelfand-Naimark-Segal (GNS) construction, for each such state, there is a *-representation $\pi_{\rho}$ of $A$ in a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}_{\rho}$ and a unit vector $\Omega\in\mathscr{H}_{\rho}$ such that $$\rho(a)=\langle\pi_\rho(a)\Omega,\Omega\rangle$$ for every $a\in A$.

Question: what conditions do two states $\rho$, $\rho'$ have to satisfy such that the associated representations be equivalent ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a criterion which is not tautological, that is, beyond the very definition of equivalence of *-representations, there are (at least) two situations where there is a criterion for equivalence of GNS representations, namely:

1. $\rho$ and $\rho'$ are *pure* states (equivalently, the GNS representations $\pi_\rho$, $\pi_{\rho'}$ associated to $\rho$, resp. $\rho'$ are *irreducible*) or
2. $\rho$ and $\rho'$ are *type III factor* states (i.e. the von Neumann algebras $\pi_\rho(A)''$, $\pi_{\rho'}(A)''$ are type III factors) and the GNS Hilbert spaces $\mathscr{H}_\rho$, $\mathscr{H}_{\rho'}$ are both *separable*.

In both cases, $\pi_\rho$ and $\pi_{\rho'}$ are equivalent iff they are *quasi-equivalent*, i.e. neither representation has a nonzero subrepresentation disjoint from the other. Generally, $\pi_\rho$ and $\pi_{\rho'}$ are quasi-equivalent iff there are trace-class positive linear operators $T_\rho\in\mathfrak{B}(\mathscr{H}_{\rho'})$, $T_{\rho'}\in\mathfrak{B}(\mathscr{H}_\rho)$ with unit trace (i.e. density matrices) such that $\rho(a)=\mathrm{Tr}(T_\rho\pi_{\rho'}(a))$ and $\rho'(a)=\mathrm{Tr}(T_{\rho'}\pi_\rho(a))$ for all $a\in A$. By Fell's equivalence theorem (Theorem 1.2 of J.M.G. Fell, *The Dual Spaces of C*-Algebras*, [Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. **94** (1960) 365-403](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1960-094-03/S0002-9947-1960-0146681-0/)), quasi-equivalence of $\pi_\rho$ and $\pi_{\rho'}$ also amounts to requiring:

- $\ker\pi_\rho=\ker\pi_{\rho'}=J$, and
- The identity map of $A/J$ extends to a *-isomorphism from $\pi_\rho(A)''$ onto $\pi_{\rho'}(A)''$.

Therefore, these two conditions together may be thought of as an equivalence criterion in situations 1.) and 2.) above.

Comment: If $\rho$ and $\rho'$ are pure then they induce equivalent representations if and only if they are unitarily conjugate (an easy consequence of Kadison transitivity).

Comment: Right, good point. Actually that is an easier criterion than the one I gave - I rather had the type III factor case in mind (which is the typical situation for local algebras of observables in relativistic quantum field theory), but since the quasi-equivalence criterion also works in the pure case, I felt I should include it as well.

Comment: Just a quick remark on how to interpret the definition of quasi-equivalence. For those who might find the definition by non-disjointness of sub-representations a little unintuitive, a quick equivalent definition is as follows: states $\rho$ and $\rho'$ are quasi-equivalent when they generate isomorphic von Neumann algebras, $\pi_\rho(A)'' \cong \pi_{\rho'}(A)''$.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine you are correct, of course, but I wanted to emphasize as well that the isomorphism may be chosen to act as the identity on $A/J$. Moreover, your definition of quasi-equivalence relies on Fell's equivalence theorem.

Comment: Quite an interesting set of criteria. Thanks! Then this brings up another question: If the representations are not equivalent when states are not unitarily equivalent, then how does one reconcile this to the usual Hilbert space formulation of Quantum Mechanics where there is just one separable Hilbert space as an axiom. Does one have to make a choice of representation depending on the state (prior to the dynamics)? Forgive my ignorance, just don't know enough about this topic. Any suggested readings (for someone with mathematical maturity but no previous background in von Nemann algebras)?

Comment: That isn't really an issue for *non-relativistic* quantum mechanics due to the Stone-von Neumann uniqueness theorem: all representations of the canonical commutation relations in Weyl form are unitarily equivalent for a *finite* number of degrees of freedom. Inequivalent representations become important for systems with infinitely many degrees of freedom, such as thermodynamic limits of quantum statistical mechanical systems and quantum field theory. In those cases, the isometric isomorphisms among all separable Hilbert spaces need (and usually do) not intertwine different GNS representations.

Comment: Finite degrees of freedom = Finite dimensional C* algebras (or the representation)? QFT translates to infinite tensor products Fock space setting...  is how I am interpreting your comment. Is that okay?

Comment: Finite degrees of freedom is *not* the same as a finite-dimensional Hilbert space or a finite-dimensional C*-algebra. Just think of a single, free, non-relativistic quantum particle in one dimension (a system with *one* degree of freedom) - the Hilbert space of the system is $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, which is definitely infinite-dimensional. In that case, the C\*-algebra of observables is generated by the Weyl unitaries $e^{itP}$, $e^{isX}$, where $s,t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $X,P$ are resp. the position and momentum operators. This C*-algebra is also infinite-dimensional.

Comment: Fock space is indeed one possible Hilbert space for QFT (albeit only for free field theories). There are many others, such as those of GNS representations associated to finite-temperature (i.e. KMS) states.

Comment: I see. I'll try yet another attempt at degrees of freedom (trying to translate to math terminology): dimensions of the base manifold?

Comment: The number of degrees of freedom is the dimension of the classical configuration space (in the sense of classical mechanics). Harmonic oscillators are simple examples where the number of degrees of finite (it can even be 1) and the dimension of the quantum Hilbert space is infinite.

Comment: The number of degrees of freedom is representation dependent. For instance all Laplace operators in dimensions $\ge 2$ are unitarily equivalent.

Comment: @jjcale but in the case you're describing the corresponding Weyl CCR C\*-algebras are *different*, so one is not really talking about different representations of the *same* Weyl CCR C\*-algebra. Robert Furber's answer is the correct one in the sense that the dimension of the classical configuration space is half the dimension of the classical phase space being quantized by the Weyl CCR C\*-algebra. Therefore, in this sense this number *is* representation-independent.

Answer (score 2):

Your title should not include *normal*, since that applies only to states on vN algebras (and possibly AW$*$ algebras).

Decades ago, George Elliott proved that if $A$ were a simple (and unital---all C$*$-algebras are unital here) AF C$*$-algebra, then any two extremal (aka *pure*) states were conjugate (via an automorphism, I think it turned out to be approximately inner). This was subsequently generalized to a much larger class, including non-simple, where the criterion applied to two extremal traces \st the kernels of the representations were equal. In this case, conjugacy is enough for equivalence (although it is not in general, consider the transposition on $\mathbf C \times \mathbf C$).

For impure states, there is not going to be much of a result, unless you know their integral decompositions.

Comment: From the other comments, it looks like vN algebras come into play anyway, so may be  normal  is not so far out? But I'll take under advisement. Thanks.